# My print statements get ignored even though the rest of the code works fine

Tags: python, printing

This code needs to loop until the users 2 inputted integers had an output of 6. And it works, except the print() statements that let the user know whether or not they won or not doesn't show up.

```
magicsix = [] 
asd = 0
fgh = 0
win = 6
while asd != win and fgh !=win:
    n1 = int(input("Enter your integer to the List: "))
    n2 = int(input("Enter your second integer to the List: "))
    magicsix.append(n1)
    magicsix.append(n2)
    print (magicsix)
    asd = sum(magicsix)
    fgh = magicsix[0] - magicsix[1] 
    if asd == win:
      print("MagicSix")
      break
    elif asd == win:
      print("MagicSix")
      break
    elif magicsix.clear(): 
      print("MagicSix not won")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `else` instead of `elif` in the last line.

```
magicsix = [] 
asd = 0
fgh = 0
win = 6
while asd != win and fgh !=win:
    n1 = int(input("Enter your integer to the List: "))
    n2 = int(input("Enter your second integer to the List: "))
    magicsix.append(n1)
    magicsix.append(n2)
    print (magicsix)
    asd = sum(magicsix)
    fgh = magicsix[0] - magicsix[1] 
    if asd == win:
        print("MagicSix")
        break
    else:
        magicsix.clear()
        print("MagicSix not won")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `else` instead of `elif` in last condition check. Also, the second condition was a duplicate. Change it to `fgh == win`.

```
magicsix = [] 
asd = 0
fgh = 0
win = 6
while asd != win and fgh != win:
   n1 = int(input("Enter your integer to the List: "))
   n2 = int(input("Enter your second integer to the List: "))
   magicsix.append(n1)
   magicsix.append(n2)
   print (magicsix)

   asd = sum(magicsix)
   fgh = magicsix[0] - magicsix[1]

   if asd == win:
     print("MagicSix")
     break
   elif fgh == win:
     print("MagicSix")
     break
   else:
     magicsix.clear()
     print("MagicSix not won")
```

You are checking the difference of the two values too for the win as I understood in `fgh = magicsix[0] - magicsix[1]`. Use

```
   fgh = max(magicsix) - min(magicsix)  # max value - min value
```

or

```
   fgh = abs(magicsix[0]- magicsix[1])  # absolute diffrenece
```

to get the absolute value when the second integer is greater than the first.